# Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded error

Tags: php, ce-1.8.1.0

When I delete many products, I got this error

> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded in
>   /magento_1.8.1/www/lib/Zend/Cache/Backend/File.php on line 655

Server php and .htaccess setting value are 1800

> cat /php/lib/php.ini |grep max_execution_time
>
> max_execution_time = 1800
>
> cat /magento_1.8.1/www/.htaccess|grep max_execution_time
>
> php_value max_execution_time 1800

What should I check?

php 7.0.16 , Magento 1.8.1

Thanks!

Comment: Try to print phpinfo(); and find max_execution_time there, but your issue is something else it should not take more than 300 seconds to delete the single product. also, check var/log folder and your nginx or apache server log

Comment: @Hitesh It happens when I delete many products (I update post). I will check what you mention. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The above error is happening because you are trying to mass delete many products from your Magento admin panel inside a browser. I can suggest you to:

1.) Delete the products in limited number.

2.) Increase your PHP execution time

3.) Write a php script to delete the products from your Magento instance and execute that php script from your command line.